# Disable Auto-clearing console (run window) in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, console

Is there any way to disable auto clearing console in Pycharm? right now each time  that we run the pycharm it clears up the console (run tool window) automatically! I need to have the history of my results

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the history of the results, consider writing the output to a file instead of the console.

If you prefer writing to the console (perhaps that's the aim of the application), you can also change the Run Configuration for your script.

In the `Run` menu, under `Edit Configurations...`, select the run configuration for your script and select the `Logs` tab (it shows the `Configuration` tab by default). On there, you'll find a checkbox to `Save console output to file`; set a file name in the field next to it.

Currently, PyCharm doesn't have an option to add a timestamp to a filename like this (although the feature has been requested by users, so it may in the future). So, you could add a few lines of code to the start of your program that only runs when debugging, moving the previous output file out of the way of for the new output.

Comment: I'd appreciate a comment if someone feels this is not a correct answer somehow - I think it's both an effective way of doing and the correct one with minimal impact to your script.